# How to edit a newly created image style?

Tags: javascript

I have a function that creates and pins an image to a chatbox. This is like "story mode" for a game I'm making. However, I was wondering what code I would use to style my posted images.

Coding that successfully creates the image:

```
function postImage(url){
    var chatbox = dom.el("chatbox");
    image = chatbox.appendChild(document.createElement("img")).src = url;
}
```

Coding that successfully creates image but fails to style it.

```
function postImage(url){
    var chatbox = dom.el("chatbox");
    var image = chatbox.appendChild(document.createElement("img")).src = url;
    image.style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 0px 0px blue";
}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
TypeError: image.style is undefined
```

Am I getting this because its failing to identify the image? But I'm not sure how to give my images a name, since I'm using the createElement tag.

Comment: `image = (...).src`

Comment: are you trying to style an src?

Comment: No i'm trying to style my image properties.

Comment: The image needs to be an actual image not the src of the image

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line

```
var image = chatbox.appendChild(document.createElement("img")).src = url;
```

sets `image` to the string `url`. The result of an assignment is always the value that was assigned.

Just don't try to combine so much:

```
function postImage(url){
    var chatbox = dom.el("chatbox");
    var image = document.createElement("img")
    chatbox.appendChild(image);
    image.src = url;
    image.style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 0px 0px blue";
}
```

Or if you really want to combine creation and appending:

```
function postImage(url){
    var chatbox = dom.el("chatbox");
    var image = chatbox.appendChild(document.createElement("img"));
    image.src = url;
    image.style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 0px 0px blue";
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir. This is what I needed! I didn't know I could set the img.src directly as a expression. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Just give some breaks to the code:

```
var image = chatbox.appendChild(document.createElement("img")); // Stop here.
img.src = url;
image.style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 0px 0px blue";
```

Answer (score 0):

You did use a wrong expression.

First you should:

```
var image = chatbox.appendChild(document.createElement("img"));
```

Than change the url:

```
image.src = url;
```

Than go on ...

With this expression `var image = chatbox.appendChild(document.createElement("img")).src = ...` you are setting the image var with `src` not with the image itself.

Try to do one command per line, mixing such type of expressions is not recommend because it is error prone for being difficult to read.